# D3.js datetime field from .csv

Tags: datetime, d3.js

I'm using a .csv containing some tweet data, the created_at field is datetime, e.g: 2018-07-17 12:08:45 (column headed: TweetTime).

Using D3.js, I want to be able to plot my tweets across a datetime x-axis. Thus far, this is proving impossible? Any advice would be amazing, please!

The relevant snippet below:

```
                d3.csv('daniellatweets180718.csv', function(data){

                    circles = svg.selectAll('.dot') 
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                            .append('circle')
                            .attr('class','dot')    
                            .attr('cx',function(d){
      var cleandate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")(d.TweetTime)
                                    console.log('test' + cleandate);
                                    return cleandate;
                             })
```

Whilst it's displaying test+ the full date is the console, it's not actually showing up with circles on my vis.

I've tried numerous things and I can't understand what is going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you refactor the `d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` outside the `enter()` loop? It does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to position in pixels an element by using a date as a pixel value. This isn't going to work. Even if you coerce a date to a primitive value, you'll get the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the epoch and this won't be equal to a pixel position you want:

```js
var date = new Date();

console.log(date.valueOf());
```

You instead want to use a scale. The d3.scaleTime will allow you to convert dates/times from a given domain to given range of output values, in this case pixel values. This might look like:

```
 var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.tweettime); }))
  .range([margin.left,width+margin.left])
```

d3.extent will provide the extent of the domain based on the provided data and property, while range will provides the extent of scaled values. With this we can scale any value in the domain to a value in the range. To scale the dates to pixel values we would use `scale(value)`:

*Scaled values of each `cx` attribute are logged for demonstration*

```js
var data = [
  {tweettime:"2018-04-04"},
  {tweettime:"2017-03-03"},
  {tweettime:"2016-02-02"},
  {tweettime:"2015-01-01"}
]; 

var width = 300;     

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", 200);
  
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.tweettime); }))
  .range([0,width])


var circles = svg.selectAll('.dot') 
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .attr('class','dot') 
   .attr("cy", 100)
   .attr("r", 10)
   .attr('cx',function(d){
      var cleandate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.tweettime)
      return scale(cleandate);
   })
   
circles.each(function(d) {
   console.log(d3.select(this).attr("cx"));
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Of course we can save a bit of time if we convert the date strings to dates first (this way we don't need to parse the date strings for the scale and to feed data to the scale, I've also added a margin on the left and right, modifying the range of the scale in the process):

```js
var data = [
  {tweettime:"2018-04-04"},
  {tweettime:"2017-03-03"},
  {tweettime:"2016-02-02"},
  {tweettime:"2015-01-01"}
]; 

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.tweettime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.tweettime);
})

var margin = {left: 20, right:20}
var width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right;     

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", 200);
  
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.tweettime; }))
  .range([margin.left,width+margin.left])


var circles = svg.selectAll('.dot') 
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .attr('class','dot') 
   .attr("cy", 100)
   .attr("r", 10)
   .attr('cx',function(d){
      return scale(d.tweettime);
   })
   
circles.each(function(d) {
   console.log(d3.select(this).attr("cx"));
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: a `Date` is the number of milli seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 GMT. That is a very big number for dates > 2000-01-01. I really want a monitor that has that horizontal pixel size.